# Why does this mean positive second crossderivatives?

Tags: real-analysis

If for $x_1 > y_1$ and $x_2 < y_2$ we have the following:

$f(x_1, y_2) - f(x_1, x_2) \geq f(y_1, y_2) - f(y_1,x_2)$

why does this translate to positive cross-partial second derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already use $x$ and $y$, so let's denote the function $f = f(a,b)$.

The condition $$f(x_1,y_2)-f(x_1,x_2) \geq f(y_1,y_2) - f(y_1,x_2)$$ tells you that as your first coordinate increases, the partial derivative with respect to your second coordinate increases because the difference $f(\cdot,y_2)-f(\cdot,x_2)$ expands. Thus $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a\partial b} \geq 0$.

If we rearrange our inequality to $$f(x_1,y_2)-f(y_1,y_2) \geq f(x_1,x_2)- f(y_1,x_2)$$ we see that as the second coordinate increases, the partial derivative with respect to the first coordinate increases, which gives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b\partial a} \geq 0$.

For more rigor, try something like:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_1,x_2+h)-f(x_1,x_2)}{h} \geq \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(y_1,x_2+h)-f(y_1,x_2)}{h}$$
which yields $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(x_1,x_2) \geq \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(y_1,x_2)$ for any $x_1>y_1$ and any $x_2$. Then you should be able to get:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(y_1+h,x_2)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(y_1,x_2)}{h} \geq 0$$

Comment: how do we prove this rigorously using the limit definition of derivatives?

Comment: @Rainroad see if my comment helps. It makes sense in my head but may still not be perfectly rigorous